# Scribd style document rendering on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, document

I have large documents (HTML or Text) (think legal documents/regulatory documents etc.) that need to made readable i.e. paged, with some rich-text markup, allowing user highlighting and annotation etc.

I was thinking of using a Scribd style rendering or as on Secwatch.com ([see here](http://secwatch.com/filings/view.jsp?formid=7044611)). Any thoughts how I can go about it? We are on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Found one article that does something similar:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ckrause/Ajax-browser-based06162006015526AM/Ajax-browser-based.aspx?ArticleID=548dfae2-4251-4c9a-b659-bfe88fd55c62

Needs some plugin, am not sure if you are OK to go for a third party control.

EDIT(s):
1) Just realized that Scribd runs of Ruby on the Rails. I guess that could be a starting point if you want to look at developing something on your own. (What does RoR have that ASP.NET doesn't for this particluar case?)
2) Scribd provides an API, but mostly for interfacing your app to sribd.com. However, it might give you ideas.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way to build something similar on my own (rather than buy). Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: I know this sounds a bit crude.. but how about converting all the documents to a PDF format when they are uploaded. Thus you could render the file into the browser and Adobe web viewer would take care of the rest.

PDF support annotations. I had implemented a custom library for rendering PDF, but in my case the format was pre-defined. Converting a document to PDF would require some library, i guess.